# Microsoft Excel; IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two `IF` statements that work perfectly on their own, but I would like to combine them into one `IF` statement;

`=IF(AND(A435="INDUSTRIAL",G435="AMONIACO NACIONAL SA DE CV"),"GOOD","WRONG")`

`=IF(AND(A441="AGRICOLA",F441="QUEMIA SA"),"BIEN","MAL")`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And, please don't shout.

Comment: How do they relate?  What happens if neither or both are true?

Answer (score 0):

If you have in the same column A **INDUSTRIAL** and **AGRICOLA** in different rows
you can use the following

`=IF(AND($A1="INDUSTRIAL",$G1="AMONIACO NACIONAL SA DE CV"),"GOOD",IF(AND($A1="AGRICOLA",$F1="QUEMIA SA"),"BIEN",IF(OR($A1="AGRICOLA",$F1="QUEMIA SA"),"MAL","WRONG")))`

In the last part **OR** you can decide for the result.

[image]